# The residue of $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f$ and $g$ be analytic near $a$, and suppose $g$ has a simple zero at $a$.  Find a formula for the residue of $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)^2}$ at $a$ in terms of $f(a)$ and the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ at $a$.

I tried using the general formula for the residue of a meromorphic function $h$ with a pole of order $2$ at $a$: $$Res_a h = \lim\limits_{z \to a} \frac{d}{dz}( h(z)(z-a)^2)$$ but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: The order of the pole depends on $f(a)$ and $f'(a)$, but given the usual set of formulas, you just need to apply de l'Hopital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(z)=s(z)(z-a)$. Then
$$
g'(z)=s(z)+(z-a)s'(z)
$$
and
$$
g''(z)=2s'(z)+(z-a)s''(z)
$$
So 
$$s(a)=g'(a) \hspace{4 mm} \text{and}  \hspace{4 mm} s'(a)=g''(a)/2
$$
So we have
$$
Res \frac{f(z)}{g(z)^2} = \lim\limits_{z \to a} \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{f(z)}{s(z)^2}\right)=\lim\limits_{z \to a} \frac{f's-2fs'}{s^3}=\frac{f'(a)g'(a)-f(a)g''(a)}{g'(a)^3}
$$